# I need to get the first OU from a Distinguishedname

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, distinguishedname

I have this PS query to get the Distinguishedname of servers:

```
 $AD = get-adcomputer -filter {OperatingSystem -like '*Server*' -and OperatingSystem -notlike '*2003*'} -property name, description, DistinguishedName | Select name, description, DistinguishedName
```

and I want to get the first instance of the OU, so I want "OU=Web Servers"

```
CN=Server1,OU=Web Servers,OU=Servers,OU=HeadOffice Servers,etc
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: I have found several useful starter post about this sort of topic just by [searching here on SO] (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+Distinguishedname+OU). I would suggest having a look at those and seeing if they help you. I want to flag this as a dup but didnt find a good one yet. Anything you have tried already?

Comment: Yes I always Google first, tried splitting but I didn't get the expected results.

Comment: _tried splitting but I didn't get the expected results._ Then you should have posted that here so we could show you where that code was not working correctly.

Comment: I tried many other ways of doing it also - don't think it would be wise to state every solution, otherwise it would be a big post to read.

Comment: There is a happy medium between showing everything and showing nothing though. Showing effort is usually more well received in cases like this. Your question reads like a code writing request.

Comment: It is - hence the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing DNs by splitting on commas is a fairly common practice, but can be unreliable because the names can contain embedded commas (they'll be escaped with a backslash).  Here's a regular expression solution that should be more reliable:

```
$dn = 'CN=Server1,OU=Web Servers,OU=Servers,OU=HeadOffice Servers,DC=domaain,DC=com'
$OU = $dn -replace '.+?,OU=(.+?),(?:OU|DC)=.+','$1'

$OU

Web Servers
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you

Comment: How to get first two OU?

Answer (score 0):

If you split the DN string and use the comma as the seperator, the OU will then be the second element in the array.

This can then be returned using square brackets to access an individual element of the array. As it's the second element we use [1] to access it, as [0] is the first element.

```
$DN = "CN=Server1,OU=Web Servers,OU=Servers,OU=HeadOffice Servers,DC=This,DC=Com"
$DN.Split(",")[1]
```

Comment: Good starting point. your example works, however if I substitute the variable as $AD = get-adcomputer "Server" | Select DistinguishedName  $AD.Split(",")[1]. I get an error: Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'split'. $AD seems to return the same as in your $DN example.

Comment: If I do  $AD -split(",") then I get the split list, one element on each line, but if I select an element ("[1]"), it splits out a character for each line

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression solution provided works only if the first element is not OU. Here is a solution that will work in any scenario and is a bit more readable for the non-regex types.
If you have the following example the splitting by "," or the regular expression solution will return 'OU=Servers', 'Servers" respectively ( I assume you want to have the OU= removed from the string )

```
$dn = 'OU=Web Servers,OU=Servers,OU=HeadOffice Servers,DC=domaain,DC=com'
($dn -split 'OU=|,OU=')[1]
```

If you don't have nested OUs then you might need to add some additional logic

```
(($dn -split 'OU=|,OU=')[1] -split ',')[0]
```